# postgres - Simplify the database operations

Tags: postgresql

I have below tables where I need to update Table-1 with Table-2 latest values without creating an intermediate temporary table. 
Table-1

```
| environment | division | item | item_cost |
| ----------- | -------- | ---- | --------- |
| 'local' | 'first' | 'item-U' | 0 |
| 'local-queue' | 'first' | 'item-U' | 0 |
| 'denmark' | 'first' | 'item-U' | 0 |
| 'local' | 'first' | 'item-C' | 0 |
| 'local-queue' | 'first' | 'item-C' | 0 |
| 'denmark' | 'first' | 'item-C' | 0 |
| 'local' | 'second' | 'item-E' | 0 |
| 'local' | 'second' | 'item-L' | 0 |
```

Table-2

```
| environment | division | item | item_cost |
| ----------- | -------- | ---- | --------- |
| 'denmark' | 'second' | 'item-E' | 1666 |
| 'local' | 'second' | 'item-E' | 4444 |
| 'denmark' | 'first' | 'item-U' | 18080 |
| 'denmark' | 'first' | 'item-U' | 18079 |
| 'local' | 'first' | 'item-U' | 55555 |
```

Is it possible to merge Table-2 into Table-1 with latest values of Table-2 get below output?

```
| environment | division | item | item_cost |
| ----------- | -------- | ---- | --------- |
| 'local' | 'first' | 'item-U' | 55555 |
| 'local-queue' | 'first' | 'item-U' | 0 |
| 'denmark' | 'first' | 'item-U' | 18080 |
| 'local' | 'first' | 'item-C' | 0 |
| 'local-queue' | 'first' | 'item-C' | 0 |
| 'denmark' | 'first' | 'item-C' | 0 |
| 'local' | 'second' | 'item-E' | 4444 |
| 'local' | 'second' | 'item-L' | 0 |
```

I have a traditional method which creates a temp table and next find and update.
I’m just wondering if there is a way to get the desired output on the fly without creating a temp table. 
Table-2 may have some entries which are not required to be shown in the output.

Thank you.

Comment: By what attribute you determine which record is the "latest"? And the need for copying data between tables likely reveals a design flaw. Looks like you should just have one table with all records and query the "latest" records from it when you need it.

Comment: actually epoch is masked as item_cost, so the greater item_cost is the latest value

Answer (score 0):

You need to think in terms of set-based operations with SQL, and assume that it is always possible.  It's a common mistake to use two sets, and try to do an update by looping through set 1 in order to update set 2, instead of doing it all in one operation using SQL.

I can answer your question but your example is unclear for at least 2 reasons:

- What is the primary key or unique identifier for each row?  You can't merge 2 lists without that defined.  I had thought it was environment, division, and item.  But you have 2 rows which both show denmark, first, item-U in Table-2.
- Your "below output" doesn't make sense.  Shouldn't the first item with cost 1666 from Table-2 be showing up in your final output?

Assuming environment, division, and item are unique, this is the correct way to merge two sets of data.  Try to insert new records, and if the keys already exist, instead update the item_cost for that key:

```
INSERT INTO table_1 (environment, division, item, item_cost)
SELECT environment, division, item, item_cost
FROM table_2
ON CONFLICT (environment, division, item)
DO UPDATE
SET item_cost = EXCLUDED.item_cost;
```

`ON CONFLICT` is supported for Postgres 9.5+.

It is even better to do the following slightly more complex operation in order to avoid redundant updates to the data if the table_2 row is already identical to the table_1 row:

```
-- Only return rows that are actually different from what is already in table_1
WITH actual_data_diff AS
(SELECT environment, division, item, item_cost
FROM table_2
EXCEPT ALL
SELECT environment, division, item, item_cost
FROM table_1)

INSERT INTO table_1 (environment, division, item, item_cost)
SELECT environment, division, item, item_cost
FROM actual_data_diff
ON CONFLICT (environment, division, item)
DO UPDATE
SET item_cost = EXCLUDED.item_cost;
```

In a reporting environment, you often get a massive amount of redundant writes and thus excessive bloat and WAL traffic, which could easily be avoided by the above pattern which only permits actual changes to go through.

There is a `MERGE` statement being actively worked on for possible release with PG12.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion. To give you more background on the case Table-2 is a kind of log table and "item_cost" is the epoch when it was last used. So, I usually do a RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY environment,division,item ORDER BY item_cost DESC) and take only the records having rank as 1.

Comment: For the question, the first item with cost 1666 from Table-2 be showing up in your final output. Yes, it is not required. It might be possible that the item is recently used but presently it is marked as inactive just after the use and hence do not want to see in the list anymore. Again do not want to delete the record because analytics team might require the data.

Comment: @deepawarrier please update your question and clarify those things - that the second input is a log table and you select only one unique record sorted by item_cost.  I would just remove the 1666 row because it's confusing.  Also, rather than using a window function, it would be better to use:
`SELECT DISTINCT ON (environment,division,item)
*
FROM table_2
ORDER BY environment, division, item, item_cost DESC`
See the docs for this here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html